# OpenServer (Сбой запуска)

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, apache, openserver

Логи:

```
2020-11-18 21:27:18  --------------------------------------------
2020-11-18 21:27:18  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Создание виртуального диска
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Обновление Hosts файла
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Обновление конфигурации MySQL-5.6-x64
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Обновление конфигурации PHP_7.3-x64
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Обновление конфигурации Apache_2.4-PHP_7.2-7.3-x64+Nginx_1.17
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Запуск MySQL-5.6-x64
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Запуск Apache_2.4-PHP_7.2-7.3-x64+Nginx_1.17
2020-11-18 21:27:19  Проверка состояния сервера
2020-11-18 21:28:11  Не удалось запустить Apache_2.4-PHP_7.2-7.3-x64+Nginx_1.17
2020-11-18 21:28:11  Не удалось запустить MySQL-5.6-x64
2020-11-18 21:28:11  Сбой запуска!
2020-11-18 21:28:11  --------------------------------------------
2020-11-18 21:28:11  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2020-11-18 21:28:11  Остановка системных модулей
2020-11-18 21:28:12  Отключение виртуального диска
2020-11-18 21:28:12  Сервер успешно остановлен за 1,329 секунд!
```

После переустановки сетевого драйвера, начались такие вот проблемы, скачал самую новую версию 5.3.7, не помогло.
Скрины ошибок запуска:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переустановил Windows 10 LTSC X64 на Windows 10 Enterprise X64, скачал самую свежую версию и всё запустилось!

Answer (score 1):

Закройте апаче и затем запустите "запуск от Администратора"

Comment: всё также, не помогло!

Comment: @КйокаРай антивирусы есть? могут блокировать.

Comment: виндовс полностью чистый, антивирусов нету, вирусов тоже, даже сам виндовс защитник выключен